# Sending JSON object to ASPNET controller method and body content is null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I was trying to figure out how I get the body of the JSON object, that I was sending with the listed AJAX POST request. 
While debugging the UploadJSON method gets called but is having a jsoninput with null content.

```
 //ASP.NET Core
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadJSON([FromBody] IFormCollection jsoninput)
    {

        var inputBody = jsoninput;


        // Writing JSON object content into a file....

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

//javascript
            function uploadJSON(plistArrayForJSON) {
            var sendobj = JSON.stringify({ plistArrayForJSON });
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://localhost:5001/home/uploadjson',
                type: 'POST',
                data: sendobj,
                contentType: "application/json",
            });
        }
```

Comment: change jsoninput instead plistArrayForJSON

Comment: You could also try `[FromBody]JObject jsoninput`.

Comment: What is `plistArrayForJSON`? Why are you using `IFormCollection` instead of binding to a model?

Comment: i thought there would be also a way to do it without an extra model.

Answer (score -1):

The JSON you send is not deserializable as `IFormCollection`.

```
//ASP.NET Core
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UploadJSON([FromBody] IList<PlayList> jsoninput)
{

    var inputBody = jsoninput;


    // Writing JSON object content into a file....

    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

Comment: And what makes you think it would be deserializable as `IList<PlayList>`, whatever `PlayList` is? You also changed the parameter name so this doesn't even compile.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it's just a sample. why are you so angry !